# Should I be using the for-loop construct or the forEach method for iteration?

Tags: javascript

Is one way more efficient? Are there any limitations in one method versus the other? Thanks for any input you guys can give me ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/ForEach) method is part of the ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification, is available on [all browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) but not in IE.

I would suggest you to use a simple sequential `for` loop, IMO is more efficient since `forEach` needs a callback function, a function will be created starting a closure and you don't need to care about IE.

But if you want to use `forEach` and all the other new `Array.prototype` methods such as [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Map), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Filter), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Every), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Some), etc... you can add an implementation for IE, in the pages I linked.

Comment: just a note: forEach is more efficient on, so far, Opera and Chrome.

Comment: I find `forEach` lightning fast on Firefox, I've made a simple [performance test](http://jsbin.com/oguho/2), feel free to [play with it](http://jsbin.com/oguho/2/edit).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to for each but supported in all browsers

```
for (var i = 0, myArrayElement; myArrayElement = myArray[i]; i++) { 
   //now you can just use 
  // myArrayElement
  // instead of 
  // myArray[i]
}
```

Just to be aware, I use this when iterating though form collections (ie document.forms[0].elements)

Comment: Just take note that the loop will be braked prematurely if an array element value is *falsy* (`0`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, an empty string,  and of course `false`). Try with `var myArray = [0, 1, 2];`

Comment: Good Point CMS.  Just to be aware I use this when iterating though form collections (ie document.forms[0].elements)

Comment: you should stick the comment you just made in your main reply.  Then we can +1 you.

Comment: `for (var x,i=0; x=data[i++];) {...}` is another way of doing this, but it still has the 'falsy' problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971698/how-to-do-it-more-efficiently/2972364#2972364, see #7 for an example of how to do it without requiring items evaluating to `true`, although it's quite messy :-)